# How to generate MD5 hash only with numbers or only with characters in java

Tags: java, hash

In my homework there is a requirement that i need to generate a MD5 hash for password with MessageDigest and DatatypeCoverter, i was able to generate a MD5 hash from input password and its a string like this:

```
input: minh
hash: C92F1D1F2619172BF87A12E5915702A6
```

but there is another requirement which is generating a hash from input password but the hash only contain numbers or characters. I ve been looking for solution all over the place, what can i do?

Comment: using md5 is not a good idea, it's weak.

Comment: Your current hash only contains numbers, they are in hex - convert it to octal and you will only have "digits".

Comment: @RC. That is tidally irrelevant to the question , despite being of general interest.

Comment: Its just a basic homework for practice, i understand that MD5 is way outdated, but i need it for an answer for this problem

Comment: @ElliottFrisch i used DatatypeCoverter.printHexbinary so all i have to do is switching it to octal right?

Answer (score 1):

You already have a "number" - because MD5 digests are just numbers. If you have to "show" them as numbers, you can store the MD5 as a BigInteger using the String, int constructor `new BigInteger(str,16);` (it's a base 16 number in a String).

If you need the decimal representation you can use BigInteger's `toString` method; the hex representation - or any base, really - can be obtained by using the `toString(int)` overload. The integer is the 'base' you want to represent the number in.

Comment: You can't store MD5 in `long`.

Comment: please, edit the answer to put it into a BigInteger? I have no time right now, otherwise I'll fix it later.

Comment: @Oleg I changed it.